# change a pageDataSource page

Tags: asp.net

Hi all i have a page that takes items from a sql datasource and puts them into a repeater. I want to know how to change the page index of the pagedDatasource when i click another button

page load

```
    DataSourceSelectArguments arg = new DataSourceSelectArguments();

    arg.MaximumRows = 8;
    arg.AddSupportedCapabilities(DataSourceCapabilities.Page);



    DataView set = (DataView)SQLDataSourceProducts.Select(arg);
    int rows = arg.TotalRowCount;
    PagedDataSource paged = new PagedDataSource();
    paged.DataSource = set;
    paged.AllowPaging = true;
    paged.PageSize = 3;
    int pageIndex = 1;
    paged.CurrentPageIndex = pageIndex - 1;

    RepeaterProducts.DataSource = paged;
    RepeaterProducts.DataBind();
```

On a button press

```
protected void moreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Change the pageIndex 

}
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi all found the answer and this is how i done it for anyone who wants to know

```
public void popRepeater()
{
    //Clear datasource so you can repopulate without getting duplication error 
    SQLDataSourceProducts.SelectParameters.Clear();

    //Your query
    SQLDataSourceProducts.SelectParameters.Add


    DataSourceSelectArguments arg = new DataSourceSelectArguments();

    arg.MaximumRows = 8;
    arg.AddSupportedCapabilities(DataSourceCapabilities.Page);



    DataView set = (DataView)SQLDataSourceProducts.Select(arg);
    int rows = arg.TotalRowCount;
    PagedDataSource paged = new PagedDataSource();

    paged.DataSource = set;
    paged.AllowPaging = true;
    paged.PageSize = 3;
    //int pageIndex = 1;
    paged.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage ;

    RepeaterProducts.DataSource = paged;
    RepeaterProducts.DataBind();
}

public int CurrentPage
{
    get
    {
        // look for current page in ViewState
        object o = this.ViewState["_CurrentPage"];
        if (o == null)
            return 0; // default page index of 0
        else
            return (int)o;
    }

    set
    {
        this.ViewState["_CurrentPage"] = value;
    }
} 

protected void moreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    CurrentPage += 1;
    popRepeater();

}
```